# Best Way to Remove Functionality from Java Spring Boot App at Build

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven-plugin, properties-file

I'm looking for a way to conditionally remove functionality from my Spring Boot app during the build. Whether that is a Maven plugin that strips out the actual Java classes or packages, or just is able to set a variable that cannot be later changed environmentally.

My spring boot app has a bunch of reports that can be generated but they shouldn't all be available in every environment they are deployed in. I would like an easy build config file where I can set which reports are enabled and disabled before build. I need them hard set at build, so someone with control of the environment can't just go in and update an associated property value and they become enabled again.

I was looking for some plugin that would remove classes or packages, or that could hardcode the variable value into the compiled class files but couldn't find anything. I figure there must be some way to make configuration stuck at build time. Have been unsuccessful finding a way to set properties at build that cannot be overridden.

Comment: It sounds like you're referring to "Build Variants".  This is where you may have packages called /release or /debug or /whatever and they can contain alternate code or configurations based on your target variant at compile time.  Something like that?

Comment: search keywords `maven profile dev prod` , there are more result or examples show how to use different file in different environment.

Comment: Try looking for SPI java... You will be able to add  functionalities implementations as dependencies to be used on build